# Two banks in two countries. Is it possible to have a unique PayPal account?

Tags: currency, paypal

I am Italian living in Sweden. 
I have one bank account in Italy and one in Sweden. I have recently opened a PayPal account in Sweden and I have no problems in performing purchasing in SEK, but I want to perform purchasing in EUR as well. 
I can use PayPal to purchase goods in EUR, but then I have to pass through the PayPal exchange rate SEK -> EUR. I want to avoid this as I have "natively" EUR in my Italian bank account and therefore I rather pay directly in EUR.

So I added another currency to my PayPal account. Now I have EUR and SEK.
I wanted to recharge my balance with EUR from my italian bank, but it does not seem to be possible.
It seems that I can recharge my PayPal balance (regardless if EUR or SEK) ONLY from the Swedish bank and only in SEK. In reality I want to add EUR in my PayPal balance from my Italian bank and SEK in my PayPal balance from my Swedish bank. It does not seem to be possible.

The only way to circumnavigate this issue is to open a second PayPal account, that I can top up in EUR from my Italian bank and that I will use only for EUR purchases. This would require to have two email addresses, two PayPal accounts, etc. I would avoid that. Is there a way to do everything with just one account?

Comment: If your primary e-mail account is gmail, you can add '.' characters to create variations of your address that still get sent to you.  For example, both firstlast@gmail.com and first.last@gmail.com will go to the firstlast account.

Comment: Ok. So you are basically suggesting to create 2 paypal accounts: one with firstlast@gmail.com and the other one with first.last@gmail.com. Correct?

Answer (score 5):

The only way to link banks from different countries, it's open two paypal accounts (different email, different address). I had the same problem (Canadian and US banks) and forced to open second paypal.

See [this paypal community answer](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Adding-and-withdrawing-money/Adding-bank-accounts-from-different-countries/td-p/344252?profile.language=en-gb):

> the only bank accounts you can add to a UK account is a UK one or a US
>   one. The US account is down to the fact we are a US company. All
>   countries can only add a local bank account.

And [this paypal answer](https://www.paypal.com/au/selfhelp/article/can-i-add-a-foreign-bank-account-to-my-paypal-account-faq2105/3):

> Can I add a foreign bank account to my PayPal account? No. If you
>   registered your PayPal account as an Australia account, you can only
>   add bank accounts from banks located in Australia or in the U.S.

Comment: Yep, had the same problem, had to do the same thing. (also for me it would have been important to move money from one to the other, which isn't possible with a single paypal account anyway)

Comment: @xyious, the same for me. I moved money from US to Canada using 2 paypal accounts.