# Link Australian and Canadian bank accounts

Tags: canada, bank-account, australia, paypal

I used to live in Australia and still have my bank account active there

Now I am in Canada and have Canadian bank account

I want to add my Canadian bank to my paypal.

Paypal allows to add US bank with Australian apparently but could not find where to add my Canadian bank

I found this question that says you cannot

[Two banks in two countries. Is it possible to have a unique PayPal account?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/73361/two-banks-in-two-countries-is-it-possible-to-have-a-unique-paypal-account)

but it was since 2016

I wonder if that has changed and it is allowed to do that now? and How?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to sign up another PayPal account using another email address.

Each PayPal account can only be associated with 1 country.

To send money between 2 PayPal accounts of different country would cost 1%+ even if the currency is the same.